# endpoint outputs csv encoding issue with Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv, encoding

I have this endoint which outputs text/csv content

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("export")]
    [Produces("text/csv")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<OrderExportDto>> ExportOrders()
    {
        
        HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=orders.csv");
        var orders = await ordersService.GetOrdersForExportAsync();

        return (orders);
    }
```

Response headers:

```
Content-Type: text/csv
Date: Tue, 05 Mar 2024 10:23:21 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:ba56cb8f-fff5-4c33-9d06-46b75dfcaacd
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=orders.csv
```

everything is fine, I can open it in Excel or Number application which is default for such kind of files on MacOs everything is fine except the fact that Excel does not show properly cyrillic characters whereas Numbers application shows it fine.
I read that this problem with Excel can be related that file content does not have BOM, if that's correct then how to add BOM in this case ?

How is possible to make that Excel shows cyrillic characters properly ?

If I call this endpoint in postman then all characters showed fine, problem is only in Excel.